# Fixed menu links not working inside <article> tag

Tags: html, css

Looking at this example: http://tympanus.net/Development/ArticleIntroEffects/index2.html

I tried to create a fixed menu that would show up to the left while scrolling through the article text. My problem is the menu links aren't clickable once the menu is horizontally parallel to where the article-tag starts.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.se">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#details">Section 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#FAQ">Section 3</a></li>
</ul>
<article>
   //whatever
</article>
```

and the CSS:

```
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 8em;
  margin-top: -2.5em;
}
```

Comment: what's the difference between your code and [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/kya5xkzd/)? The links appear to be clickable.

Comment: I have no idea. This is the source code I downloaded: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/05/22/inspiration-for-article-intro-effects/ and I just added the menu before the article-tag in the index2.html file

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own problem. The article had z-index: 1000 so I just put z-index: 1001 in the menu css and it worked!